# Create a Bootstrap like box

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a box like in bootstrap samples? I want to create a box similar to this:

[image]

Is this created with just bootstrap or with some CSS? What I tried so far is just this:

```
<div class="thumbnail clearfix">
    test
</div>
```

This only creates the outer box but I want also to have a box like that sample and the below margin

Comment: You could inspect their element to see how they did it...

Comment: Why not just see the css for that class and it's likely to be in bootstrap.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not part of the `bootstrap.css`.. the Bootstrap 2.x docs includes custom CSS to create the example blocks..

```
.bs-docs-example {
position: relative;
margin: 15px 0;
padding: 39px 19px 14px;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

.bs-docs-example:after {
content: "Example";
position: absolute;
top: -1px;
left: -1px;
padding: 3px 7px;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
color: #9da0a4;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 4px 0;
-moz-border-radius: 4px 0 4px 0;
border-radius: 4px 0 4px 0;
}
```

http://bootply.com/97038